# How to tap on button using XY coordinates in UIAutomator with Java?

Tags: java, android, ui-automation, android-uiautomator

I have in Appium/Python :

```
//calculation max_height
//calculation of max_width
action = TouchAction(self.driver)
action.tap(None, max_width, max_height).release().perform()
```

My goal is to perform same, but in Java using UIautomator tool. I have tried the next script, but it does not work.

```
UiObject appButton = new UiObject(new UiSelector());
appButton.click(int x, int y);
```

My app made in Unity and i do not have any locator's accessibility, so i have to use XY position on the screen.

Does anybody solve this issue? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way I did it was with `UIDevice`, and not `UIObject` (UIObject worked for calling specific methods or actions within the app, but UIDevice worked for device things, like clicking on X/Y, or pushing the back/home buttons)

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class SomeClass {
.... some setup and stuff...

    @Test
    public void testCoordinates() {
        UiDevice device = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
        device.click(42, 242);
    }
}
```

Where 42 is X, and 242 is Y, starting from top left corner of the screen.

Comment: Great. Thank you so much. Works.

Comment: Cool. Mark it as accepted so it can help somebody else in the future

Comment: How to click the same with in Appium Java